# Что такое deploy приложения?

Tags: github, deploy

Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами, что такое deploy приложения? И зачем нужны такие сервисы как Netlify и Vercel, если можно загрузить проект на GitHub и пользоваться ссылкой, которую создаст GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы ваше приложение было доступно пользователям - оно должно быть доступно на их компах/телефонах etc. Его можно либо установить на девайсы пользователей или дать им доступ через браузер. Чтобы получить доступ через браузер - пользователям надо ввести в его адресную строку адрес в сети. В общем случае - сети Интернет. В итоге этот адрес сети будет указывать на какой-то конкретный компьютер, на котором запущена ваша программа.

Соответственно `deploy` - это процесс разворачивания вашего приложения на этом конкретном компьютере, который будет доступен пользователям через их сетевое соединение. В процесс разворачивания приложения входят этапы сборки артефакта (например файла или папок с файлами программы), создание копии артефакта на конкретном компьютере и указание программе-вебсерверу запускать файлы программы при определённых запросах от юзеров.

Разные компании предоставляют платные/бесплатные решения для облегчения разных этапов процесса. На GitHub ваше приложение находится по адресу GitHub и на его компах. С остальными сервисами - аналогично. Из рисков - вас могут в любой момент на этих сервисах забанить и ваша программа пропадёт из сети, как это стало Parler, например.

Также вы не обладаете полным контролем над ссылкой на ваше приложение - её тоже могут в любой момент изменить. И вы ограничены (в случае GitHub) как минимум тем, что в ссылке всегда будет `github`, например.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, deploy - это выкладывание своего рабочего кода на какой-то хостинг, который будет
запускать ваш код всё время, вот например у вас есть свой бот и вам нужно чтобы он
постоянно работал. Разве вы будете ради этого бота оставлять постоянно включенным пк и   ъ
запускать на нём скрипт? Нет, а так вы выкладываете на хостинг свой бот и он будет
автоматически перезагружаться при сбое и работать 24/7.
Чево же не использовать только GitHub?
Потому-что как вы запустите бота, сайт и тд на GitHub? Никак, но с сайти можна но тогда они
будут иметь в конце ".github.io" и он не сможет бить популярним
в гугл или других интернет браузеров.

Comment: Github Pages поддерживает пользовательские домены.